# jQuery scrollTop not working with querystring link

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation and the initial url looks like this:

`test.php?query=19`

and I have links on my page like so `<a href="#section-1">Section 1</a><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a>`

with 3 sections:

```
<section id="section-1"></section><section id="section-2"></section><section id="section-3"></section>
```

and I am using this jquery code to scroll to that section from the top of the page (or where the user is on the page) to the top of that section and not show the `#` tag in my url.

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 2000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

my issue is that this does not scroll to the section. its just goes to the section bottom of the section and then scrolls to the top and the `#` appears in my url.

I have another menu on my main home page:

`home.php` and I am using the exact same jquery code and it works on that page.

My question is how do I get the ScrollTop to work in my `test.php?query=19` page like it does on `home.php` When I click on a like on `test.php?query=19` my url changes to this: `test.php?query=19#section-1`

Comment: do you see any errors in the console ?

Comment: You say that you have the exact same code on the menu. I have 2 questions: 1) This part `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')` is the same? Because you are targetting every link in the page, and if 2) you load the script twice (menu + this page), the click handlers are added multiple times

Comment: *If* you have posted your *actual* code here... then it works as-is, and you have no problem (though the function could probably be simplified a bit). So the only answer is that the problem is *not* in the bits you posted here. Try to post your actual `HTML` and `javascript`... do cut out any completely irrelevant parts before posting (but make sure the problem still persists in whatever "minimal" code you post here). I bet you will discover where the problem is in this process when you cut out some portion that seems completely irrelevant ;)

Comment: your code works fine, the problem must lie somewhere else => http://jsfiddle.net/zx95rhs0/

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent your code from adding `#` in your current `url`

You can also use this code for scrolling to a particular section on any page:

**HTML:**

```
<div  id = 'a' style = 'height:300px;'>
123
</div>
<a href= '#b'>Go to 456 </a>

<div id = 'b' style = 'height:300px;' >
456
</div>
<a href= '#c'>Go to 789 </a>

<div id = 'c'style = 'height:300px;' >
789
</div>
<a href= '#d'>Go to asd </a>

<div id = 'd' style = 'height:300px;' >
asd
</div>
<a href= '#e'>Go to fgh </a>

<div  id = 'e'  style = 'height:300px;' >
fgh
</div>
<a href= '#a'>Go to 123 </a>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
function scroll(id){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('href')
        scroll(id);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/k19p33tm/

http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/k19p33tm/1/

Comment: nice example +1 for jsfiddle link

Answer (score 1):

I would change the logic you are handling your code.
Preventing the default event and accessing the href directly by attr.

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this).attr('href');
            if ($target.size()) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $target.offset().top
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Btw, I'm not sure about understanding the selector you're using `a[href*=#]:not([href=#])`. Also, the  condition (`if location.pathnae.blah...`) seems to be pretty awkward. I would simply do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#some-wrapper').on('click', 'a.scroll-to', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($target.size()) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $target.offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `a[href*=#]:not([href=#])` is perfectly clear... any link that has a `#` anywhere in it, but is not only a `#` (which is commonly used on links that only serve to trigger some javascript). The "awkward" `location.pathname`-condition could be a workaround to ignore any get-parameters of both the link and the current page. Your method would give very different results in some cases... though if the OP has complete control of the whole page, the workaround really shouldn't be necessary... BTW you recommend `e.preventDefault()` *before* checking if it's scrollable!?

Comment: Yes, if it's not scrollable you can then just `window.location = this.attr('href');` or similar. I didn't add this part to my answer because I assumed that you wanted to scroll every time.